# How to reference the CSS file in the APP on the web page

Tags: html, css, ios, swift

I have an iOS app, and I've written a section of local.css, which I've already placed in the Assets of my iOS Xcode project. Now, I have a webpage on a server, for example, http://test.com/test.htm. If this webpage wants to use the local.css from my app, how should the CSS path be written within the webpage? ( <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=???????? local.css">) Thank.

I tried using  but it didn't work.

Comment: Other than your app providing its own local HTTP server, I don't see how this could possibly work.

Comment: You would have to hold that local css on a local server and then use the hostname to that server - be aware though that it would only work whilst looking at it on that specific machine and it would 404 from everywhere else

Answer (score 0):

If your Assets folder is directly under the root folder of your application, then you can use ⁠ `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Assets/local.css">`.